# MVC PayPal Helper error: PayPal.Platform.SDK.FATALException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paypal

I was using PayPal helper http://paypalhelper.codeplex.com and was getting an error `PayPal.Platform.SDK.FATALException`

After that i took the source code too have look what is happening there and after i debug one of the tests in the test project `public void TestImplicitSimplePay()` and find out that it is throwing an error in the class `SoapEncoder` in method `Decode` in line `96 return (object)serializer.Deserialize(reader);`

```
public static object Decode(string soapEnvelope, Type toType)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = null;

            try
            {
                /// Initializing the XMLSerializer.
                serializer = new XmlSerializer(toType);

                /// Removing SOAP outer Envelope
                soapEnvelope = soapEnvelope.Replace("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Header /><soapenv:Body>", string.Empty);
                soapEnvelope = soapEnvelope.Replace("</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>", string.Empty);
                soapEnvelope = soapEnvelope.Replace("xmlns:ns2=\"http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap\"", string.Empty);
                soapEnvelope = soapEnvelope.Replace("ns2:", string.Empty);
                soapEnvelope = soapEnvelope.Replace("soapenv:", string.Empty);
                soapEnvelope = soapEnvelope.Replace("ns3:", string.Empty);
                soapEnvelope = soapEnvelope.Replace("xmlns:ns2=\"http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap\"", string.Empty);

                /// Deserializing and Returning the XML
                using (MemoryStream reader = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapEnvelope)))
                {
                    return (object)serializer.Deserialize(reader); //Error here
                }                
            }
            catch (FATALException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FATALException("Error occurred in SoapEncoder->Decode method", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                serializer = null;
            }
        }
```

soapEnvelope xml:

```
<xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
        <Header/>
        <Body>
            <PayResponse >
                <responseEnvelope>
                    <timestamp>2011-08-09T00:28:53.399-07:00</timestamp>
                    <ack>Success</ack>
                    <correlationId>621854fd57929</correlationId>
                    <build>2012864</build>
                </responseEnvelope>
                <payKey>AP-1SE162159L922805T</payKey>
                <paymentExecStatus>COMPLETED</paymentExecStatus>
        </PayResponse>
```

May be some one come across that and know what i can do to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
soapEnvelope = soapEnvelope.Replace("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Header /><soapenv:Body>", string.Empty);
```

With:

```
soapEnvelope = soapEnvelope.Replace("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body>", string.Empty);
```

The response from Paypal seems to have altered slightly and the `<soapenv:Header />` node no longer has a space before the self closing tag ends.